# How to count intersections between columns with non-null values and row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hey so the title might be hard to understand so basically here's a small sample of my DataFrame.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   J   K   action
0                       22                  noise
1                           68              junk
2                   93                      junk
3           80                              junk
4                                   57      noise
```

The actions column only has two values (noise and junk). For instance in the first initial row column 'F' has a value of 22 and it's action is noise, and I want to count how many times 'F' has a non-null value when action is 'noise' and 'F' when action is 'junk'. Of course I want to count this for all the other single letter columns also. So I want to have a dictionary that likely looks like this where the inner dictionary has counts per action.

```
{'F': {'noise': 1, 'junk': 0},
 'G': {'noise': 0, 'junk': 1},
 'E': {'noise': 0, 'junk': 1},
 'C': {'noise': 0, 'junk': 1},
 'J': {'noise': 1, 'junk': 0}
}
```

I've tried going through with df.iterrows() and df.notnull() but I can't seem to get the logic right.

edit - Updated the expected output.

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't seem right for your sample data

Comment: Oh, sorry that example output was just me giving a really random example, I'll edit it to actually mirror the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `notnull()` to mask your `df`, `groupby` each action and simply `sum`

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].notnull().astype(int).groupby(df.action).sum().to_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly! Could it be possible to explain what's happening here? My take is that the .iloc statement indexes the whole dataframe, then notnull()  changes them to boolean values and .astype(int) only retains the columns with integers?

Comment: @animusdx Glad it helped! `iloc` just removes the last column (i.e. we just select columns from `A` to `K`). `notnull()` will transform the dataframe such that every value that is `NaN` becomes `False`, and every other becomes `True`. Then, `astype(int)` makes these `0` and `1` respectively (so that we can sum them ! :] ). Then, simply groupby action and sum. The `to_dict` method is built in and creates the final dictionary!

Comment: Thanks again for the help! If it wasn't evident I'm a novice with pandas and working with it is like opening a whole can of worms.